# Google Cloud Stackdriver - how can I group logs by summary field?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a log query that shows me the `booking` and `distribution` container log. To have a more clear overview over the call flow over the different services - I'd like to group those two logs into wrapper that I can expand if necessary.

Take the screenshot as an example. I'd love to have only **2** log entries here that are grouped either by `booking` or `distribution`.

**Q:** Is there a way to group by "summary"?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to "group" the log entries ? For exporting them ? Is there any goal of this that you didn't mention ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add a custom field using a line in the summary, but this only works on the `Legacy log viewer`. You can go there by clicking the `Options` button at the top of the `Logs explorer` page.

1. Go to `Legacy Log viewer`
2. Expand the summary
3. Click on the line in the summary you want to group
4. Click `Add fields to summary line`

See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview?&_ga=2.189612139.-1388801832.1588033546&_gac=1.137487620.1599017928.EAIaIQobChMIyJyW-MXJ6wIVDBdgCh3FkQQVEAAYASAAEgI6rvD_BwE#custom-fields) for the official documentation about the topic on adding custom fields in Legacy Logs Viewer.